# UIAlertView not appearing

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

Hi all I am having trouble with getting a LoginAlert to appear when app is launched...the app builds successfully but the alert view does not appear. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for any and all insights!

```
//  TimelineTableViewController.swift


import UIKit

class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if ((PFUser.currentUser()) != nil){
            var loginAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up / Login",message: "Please Sign up or Login",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
                textfield in
                textfield.placeholder = "Your username"
            })

            loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
                textfield in
                textfield.placeholder = "Your password"
                textfield.secureTextEntry = true
             })

            loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{
                alertAction in
                let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
                let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
                let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextfield.text, password: passwordTextfield.text){
                    (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                    if ((user) != nil){
                        println("Login successful")
                    }else{
                        println("Login Failed")
                    }

                }

            }))

            loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{
                alertAction in
                let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
                let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
                let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

                var poster:PFUser = PFUser()
                poster.username = usernameTextfield.text
                poster.password = passwordTextfield.text

                poster.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{
                    (success:Bool!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                    if !(error != nil){
                        println("Sign Up Successful")
                    }else{
                        let errorString = error.userInfo!["error"] as String
                        println(errorString)
                    }
                }

            }))

            self.presentViewController(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make loginAlert a class variable. presentViewController does not keep a reference to the alertController. Because it is in a local variable now, it will be deleted at the end of viewDidAppear.

Comment: how would I create a class for loginAlert? (sorry I am somewhat a beginner...)

Comment: This is not an issue. when you presentViewController its retainCount will increase, so it doesn't matter its a local variable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your alert view code is working fine. I guess the problem is with your condition `if ((PFUser.currentUser()) != nil)`. Add bookmarks at `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` method to debug the issue.

Following code I have tested, you can check it by creating a new sample.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var loginAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up / Login",message: "Please Sign up or Login",
      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    
    loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
      textfield in
      textfield.placeholder = "Your username"
    })
    
    loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
      textfield in
      textfield.placeholder = "Your password"
      textfield.secureTextEntry = true
    })
    
    loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{
      alertAction in
      let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
      let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
      let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField
      print("Login with Username: \(usernameTextfield.text) -- Password: \(passwordTextfield.text)")
    }))
    
    loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{
      alertAction in
      let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
      let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
      let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField
      print("Signup with Username: \(usernameTextfield.text) -- Password: \(passwordTextfield.text)")
    }))
    
    self.presentViewController(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

[image: Screeshot of the output in iOS8/iPhone6 Simulator]

Good Luck :)